# How to get id or title onPress in react Native ListView

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native

**here is a piece of code from facebook movie sample app. how can i get movie title in a getData function. i have also used TouchableHighlight onPress but can get movie Item.how can i fetch item ids from each listitems.**

> ```
>     import React, {Component,} from 'react';
>     import {
>        AppRegistry,
>        Image,
>       ListView,
>       StyleSheet,
>       Text,
>       View,
>          } from 'react-native';
>
>      var REQUEST_URL ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/master/docs/MoviesExample.json';
>
> export default class SampleAppMovies extends Component {
>   constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     this.state = {
>       dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
>         rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
>       }),
>       loaded: false,
>     };
>   }
>
>
>
> componentDidMount() {
>     this.fetchData();
>   }
>
>   fetchData() {
>     fetch(REQUEST_URL)
>       .then((response) => response.json())
>       .then((responseData) => {
>         this.setState({
>           dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.movies),
>           loaded: true,
>         });
>       })
>       .done();
>   }
>
>     // I need id movie name here
>   _getData = (name) =>{
>     console.log(name);
>   }
>
>   render() {
>     if (!this.state.loaded) {
>       return this.renderLoadingView();
>     }
>
>     return (
>       <ListView
>         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
>         renderRow={this.renderMovie}
>       />
>     );
>   }
>
>   renderLoadingView() {
>     return (
>       <View style={styles.container}>
>         <Text>
>           Loading movies...
>         </Text>
>       </View>
>     );
>   }
>
>   renderMovie(movie) {
>     return (
>       <View style={styles.container}>
>         <Image
>           source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
>           style={styles.thumbnail}
>         />
>         <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
>           <Text style={styles.title} onPress={this._getData(movie)}>{movie.title}</Text>
>           <Text style={styles.year}>{movie.year}</Text>
>         </View>
>       </View>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: whenever you press text of an item it will be rerendered and it will call a function as described by you..and the data will be received in that function..

Comment: @Codesingh can you demonstrate?

Comment: are getting anything in this  console.log(name); ?

Comment: Getting this error : undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this._getData(movie)')

Comment: bind _getData(movie) function like this : this._getData.bind(this,movie)

Comment: again same error : undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this._getData.bind')

Comment: ok now i have to write code so see my answer..

Comment: before that declare the function like this .... _getData (name){
    console.log(name);
  }

Comment: Hi Saurabh, 
Did you found any solution for above issue because i am facing same issue

Comment: @Sau_Patil Yes i have cleared that issue